# Can't get the $_SESSION signed in username?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the username that is signed in, but it wont work. Check this:

I've tried:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

and I just get the

> error: Notice: Undefined index: username

I know I have a 'variable' that is named `username`...

And i've also tried:

```
echo  $_GET['username'];
```

but that wont work either, same error.

And i have `session_start()` and I have signed in to the database

Comment: have you assigned value for $_SESSION['username']

Comment: Show the code where you are assigning the username session.

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework by any chance ? how are you authenticating users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first aid. In php that is print_r

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

print_r will show the hole session array if username is not there, you must asign a value first to it

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_GET['username'];  // for example
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure when you set the $ _SESSION was you put session_start ()

Answer (score 0):

You must manually assign a value to `$_SESSION['username']`. It is not put there automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Variables stored in the `session` are put there by your code - if you havent assigned anything to `$_SESSION['username']` then you will recieve the error message `Undefined index` .. here is a basic example of using sessions :

```
<?php
// page1.php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #1';
$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green'; // set a value
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';
```

then on page 2 :

```
<?php
// page2.php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';
echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
```

In this simple example you can see that in page 1 you set a value `$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';` and then in page you retrieve the value '$_SESSION['favcolor']`

[All docs for sessions are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)